# WinForms - groupBox as in WinApi

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

In `Win32 API` the `BS_GROUPBOX` just creates a 'button' that is basically painted as a group, it doesn't serve as a container for any other control.

In WinForms, this concept was changed and GroupBox is actually a container.

I'm porting an old `Win32` app to `WinForms` where I generate at run-time dialog forms by parsing a `Win32 API` dialog definition string. Everything works fine, except these groupBoxes, for which I cannot find an alternative in .NET world.

How would I get a control ala Win32 GroupBox that doesn't take any ownership as the `.NET GroupBox`?

Thx

Comment: Looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it certainly does look as if it always was meant to contain sets of controls and is not really functioning as a button. So __why not__ use the GroupBox control?

Comment: I checked that article, and it clearly says, that groupBox is mainly to create visual groups only. The GroupBox is a container, and that creates lots of issues when parsing the string and placing the control in the correct parent.

Comment: Well if it helps you __can__ place controls __over__ instead of __into__ a GroupBox; in the designer for example by moving it with the keyboard and in code by simply not adding them to the GB's Controls collection.

Comment: yeah, the problem, is that we have controls under those groups, so now the forms are empty :)

Comment: Setting the z-order should help, shouldn't it? And getting it right must have been part of the original code, too, no? Or was the original 'group-button' transparent as well?

Answer (score 0):

After all I solved the problem by creating a Transparent GroupBox in .NET. Here is the code.

```
 public sealed class IGTransparentGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        public IGTransparentGroupBox()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20;
                return cp;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            Parent?.Invalidate(Bounds, true);
            base.OnBackColorChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnParentBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
            base.OnParentBackColorChanged(e);
        }
    }
```